# Sort string field as number

Tags: soql

I want to get records from custom object sort by a field as number. The field I want to sort is string type. Is there any way to do that? I am storing result in list, is there a way to sort list based on the string field but sort it as number?

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround you can create a formula field of type Number and define it as:

```
VALUE(My_String_Field__c)
```

Then just sort on this formula field instead.

Comment: I cannot modify add fields in custom object, it belongs to a managed package by someone else.

Answer (score 2):

If the field contains only numbers, then just using `ORDER BY` in your SOQL should work as you expect.  Or, if it must be done after the records are in memory, you could create a wrapper class that implements the `Comparable` interface and manipulate the fields as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for giving pointers @AndrewMonshizadeh. I already tried sort by, it does not work as I want. Can you provide some sample on comparable interface?

My SOQL query retuns lots of fields.. I was avoiding to have wrapper class, but it looks no choice :(

Comment: Does your text field actually contain only numbers? Also, according to [the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) there are a few field types where `ORDER BY` does not apply.

Comment: It does only contain numbers.

Comment: @Sanjivani [here is a link to the documentation on custom sort order](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm#CustomSortSection). There you will find a complete example of how to implement a custom sort order, along with a test class for that custom sort order.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMonshizadeh, I can use this example next time when I will need to do custom sorting.
For the time being I applied some other logic, because the field has values like 1,1.1,2,2.1.1,2.1.2, so they are not numbers. Since I already applied different logic, I will keep your solution bookmarked for next time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is pseudo code of what I have done to sort list by field:

1. theList=[SOQL query of fields]
2. loop through the List to create map
   theMap=key=sortField, value=theList.object

I calculated key as per my requirement for sorting, the valyes in key are like 2.3.4, so i stored it as 2.34 for sorting purpose.

1. Set keySet = theMap.keySet();
2. List keyList = new List();
   keyList.addAll(keySet);

   keyList.sort();
3. initialise list again to fill in new sorted entries

   theList=new List();

   //iterate from the first to the last key
    for (Integer i = 0; i < keyList.size(); i++)
    {
     theList.add(i element from map)
     }